# Python- Integer input, error message for entering letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("this program will calculate the area")

input("[Press any key to start]")

width = int(input("enter width"))

while  width < 0 or width > 1000:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))

height = int(input("Enter Height"))

while  height < 0 or height > 1000:
    print("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    widht = int(input("Enter Height"))

area = width*height

print("The area is:",area
```

i have added a error message for entering a digit lower or higher then stated, however if possible i would like to display an error message to the user if they enter a Letter or nothing at all.

Comment: Okay, so you need to write some code to do that. There's none here.

Comment: Line 15: you spelled 'height' wrong as width, which was still wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrap the line input line in a try except:

```
try:
 width = int(input("enter width"))
except:
 width = int(input("enter width as integer"))
```

or better: wrap it in a function:

```
def size_input(message):
   try:
      ret = int(input(message))
      return ret
   except:
      return size_input("enter a number")

width = size_input("enter width")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try-except`, `int()` raises an exception if the argument passed to it is invalid :

```
def valid_input(inp):
    try:
        ret=int(inp)
        if not 0<ret<1000:
            print ("Invalid range!! Try Again")
            return None
        return ret
    except:
        print ("Invalid input!! Try Again")
        return None
while True:
    rep=valid_input(input("please chose a number between 0-1000: "))
    if rep:break
print(rep)
```

**output:**

```
please chose a number between 0-1000: abc
Invalid input!! Try Again
please chose a number between 0-1000: 1200
Invalid range!! Try Again
please chose a number between 0-1000: 123abc
Invalid input!! Try Again
please chose a number between 0-1000: 500
500
```