# How would I type a string in an int input without getting an Error in Python?

Tags: python, valueerror

I was wondering how I would allow my input to allow both strings and int. For example, if I wanted to type 'string' I wouldn't get an error. But when I type a string into it I get this error: **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string'** I know I have an int() at the start of the input line but I've tried other things and it still doesn't work. This is the code:

```
 row = int(input('Which row do you want to change?: '))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284652/python-integer-input-error-message-for-entering-letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the input rather than arbitrarily converting it to integer.

```
row = input('Which row do you want to change?: ')
if row.isdigit():
    row = int(row)
else:
    print("That's a string")
```

Comment: I thank you, sir! I didn't know there was a way to validate the input like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        age = int(input("Which row do you want to change? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following, it can detect all whole numbers. It converts the string input into integer type only if the input is numeric, unlike your case. You can thereby allow both integer and string inputs.

```
row = input('Which row do you want to change?: ')
if row.isnumeric():
    row = int(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if u wanna stop your code or use a else

```
user_awnser = input("how much character would you like? ")
try:
    awnser = int(user_awnser)
except ValueError:
    print("not possible")
    exit()
```